# issue with packing struct in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I am trying to back the following struct on ideone, but I keep getting runtime issues for the following code :

```
from struct import *
Version  = 0xC0DE
DefaultUsername = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' # this must always be 16 characters long


def insert_username( name ):
    return name + DefaultUsername[len(name) : ]

join_request = pack('ii4c16c',Version, 0x7777, 'JOIN', insert_username('justin') )
```

Also, I would like to apply a crc32 function - it takes a byte array ; would I be able to put join_request in another pack struct along with the 32 crc byte result?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specification `c` in the format string requires a single character argument. You pass multi-character strings, so you need the `s` specifications. However, the `s` spec requires binary strings (bytes), so convert your string arguments to byte arrays:

```
join_request = pack('ii4s16s',Version, 0x7777, b'JOIN', insert_username('justin').encode())
```

The result is a byte array.